# Invite more external testers to TestFlight build?

Tags: ios, testflight

I'm about to invite a bunch of external testers to our pre-release (it's already been approved by Apple). Once I "Send Invites", is it possible to **invite more testers to the same build**. Or would I have to create another pre-release.

I can't find a clear answer in the TestFlight docs. Thanks in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, no problem. Later you can invite more external users: they will be offered the current build.